# Three.js dirtyVertices doesn't work

Tags: javascript, webgl, three.js

I created a 12*12 plane in three.js, and I tried to edit it's verticles between 2 rendering, but it doesn't work.

I added this code, but nothing changed:

```
ground.geometry.dynamic = true;
ground.geometry.__dirtyVertices = true;
ground.geometry.computeCentroids();
```

Code here: http://jsfiddle.net/vpBEG/2/

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to reset your flags after each render:

```
ground.geometry.verticesNeedUpdate = true;
```

See the [update to your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vpBEG/5/)

Answer (score 3):

For Three.js r.49 you need to use

```
ground.geometry.verticesNeedUpdate = true;
```

See the wiki: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/wiki/Updates

Comment: Did you read the wiki in the link above? It said "Once buffers change, these flags reset automatically back to false. You need to keep setting them to true if you want to keep updating buffers."